# How do I remove outgoing changesets in Mercurial (hg)

Tags: version-control, mercurial

when I run `hg out` I have 3 outgoing changesets. I want to trash them and revert to how things are in the central repository. How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `hg strip 'roots(outgoing())'`

Comment: You can also specify a target for the outgoing changesets (if you have no default repo or you want to strip relative to another repo) using `hg strip 'roots(outgoing(target-name))'`.

Comment: Thanks @JasonR.Coombs that's super useful. I was curious how change the outgoing() based on the changesets other than the default remote repo url.

Answer (score 3):

Either reclone from the central repo, or use `clone -r` to reclone only the needed changesets.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to use `hg strip` [command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Strip), which is part of the `mq` ([mercurial queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension)) extension.

The mercurial philosophy is of an immutable history, so commands which manipulate that history are frowned upon, but there are times when stripping or rebasing may solve more problems than they cause.

If you use [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) then you will need to [enable the MQ extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension#Configuration). Prior to v1.0 THG it was enabled by default, but after much discussion it was decided that it was really an 'advanced' feature that should be left off until the use has the experience to know how to enable it.